# create-react-native-app packager is stuck at starting

Tags: react-native

[image]

The folder created using the following structure fails to start the packager

```
create-react-native-app AwesomeProject

cd AwesomeProject
npm start
```

My set up is :

```
OS: Windows 10
Node: 10.10.0
Yarn: 1.6.0
npm: 6.2.0-next.1
Watchman: Not Found
Xcode: N/A
Android Studio: Version 3.1.0.0 AI-173.4720617
```

I have tried changing the version of NPM , expo, react-native and react and I even tried to manipulate the metro bundler with no results.

```
{
  "name": "AwesomeProject",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-native-scripts": "1.14.0",
    "jest-expo": "~27.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^27.0.1",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "~0.55.2"
  }
}
```

Does this script have any logs ? where can I see what is failing and how to possibly rectify the matter.

Comment: Can you post your package.json ?

Comment: Yes, I have edited my post

Comment: does "npm install" throws any errors?